# CSV type data input to XML

Tags: c#, xml, parsing

I have very limited experience so would like to ask some of your opinions on how to approach my requirement.

I have the following data that I need to analyse and put into XML. For my first attempt I was using TextFieldParser, a lot of `CASE`statements, and `XMLWriter` to produce the XML output file. It works fine but I was sure there must be a better way to do it.

As you'll see below the input file is not straight forward and contains both strings and integers, and depending on the keyword in the first column the rest of the line has specific meaning. Each line is different and I'm not always interested in each of the columns.

In addition, in some cases certain lines (or blocks of lines) can be repeated. For instance CLIENT, INCLUDE, SCHED, etc.

For my second attempt I've started to use `XDocument` `XElement` and got some valuable input about that here at SO yesterday. I started to use this but facing some issue with passing out of/or between the `CASE` statements.

Today I read another article where it suggested to use dictionaries instead of CASE. One could incorporate a method into the dictionary, which seems like an interesting idea.

Any suggestions?

```
CLASS EIT_PX_UNIX_Adhoc *NULL* 0 760000 0 *NULL*
NAMES
INFO 0 0 0 0 *NULL* 0 0 60 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1383584093 
RES STU_PX_DD_pxddeit_files *NULL* *NULL* *NULL* *NULL* *NULL* *NULL* *NULL* *NULL* *NULL*
POOL NetBackup NetBackup NetBackup NetBackup NetBackup NetBackup NetBackup NetBackup NetBackup NetBackup
FOE 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
SHAREGROUP *ANY*
DATACLASSIFICATION *NULL*
CLIENT 10.150.131.201 HP9000-700 HP-UX11.11 0 0 0 0 *NULL*
CLIENT pxhpc053 HP9000-700 HP-UX11.11 0 0 0 0 *NULL*
CLIENT prdrpxx027 HP9000-700 HP-UX11.11 0 0 0 0 *NULL*
CLIENT prdrpxx028 HP9000-700 HP-UX11.11 0 0 0 0 *NULL*
CLIENT prdrpxx029 HP9000-700 HP-UX11.11 0 0 0 0 *NULL*
CLIENT prdrpxx030 HP9000-700 HP-UX11.11 0 0 0 0 *NULL*
INCLUDE ALL_LOCAL_DRIVES
SCHED Full 0 1 604800 13 0 0 0 *NULL* 0 0 0 0 0 0 -1 0 0 0
SCHEDWIN 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
SCHEDRES *NULL* *NULL* *NULL* *NULL* *NULL* *NULL* *NULL* *NULL* *NULL* *NULL*
SCHEDPOOL *NULL* *NULL* *NULL* *NULL* *NULL* *NULL* *NULL* *NULL* *NULL* *NULL*
SCHEDRL 13 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
SCHEDFOE 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
SCHEDSG *NULL* *NULL* *NULL* *NULL* *NULL* *NULL* *NULL* *NULL* *NULL* *NULL*
SCHED Incr 1 1 604800 13 0 0 0 *NULL* 0 0 0 0 0 0 -1 0 0 0
SCHEDWIN 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
SCHEDRES *NULL* *NULL* *NULL* *NULL* *NULL* *NULL* *NULL* *NULL* *NULL* *NULL*
SCHEDPOOL *NULL* *NULL* *NULL* *NULL* *NULL* *NULL* *NULL* *NULL* *NULL* *NULL*
SCHEDRL 13 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
SCHEDFOE 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
SCHEDSG *NULL* *NULL* *NULL* *NULL* *NULL* *NULL* *NULL* *NULL* *NULL* *NULL*

<Policy Number="5">
      <PolicyName>EIT_PX_UNIX_Adhoc</PolicyName>
      <General>
        <FollowNFS>Disabled</FollowNFS>
        <Compression>Disabled</Compression>
        <Encryption>Disabled</Encryption>
        <LimitJobsperPolicy>60</LimitJobsperPolicy>
        <CrossMountPoints>Disabled</CrossMountPoints>
        <Active>No</Active>
        <CollectTIR>No</CollectTIR>
        <MultipleDataStreams>Yes</MultipleDataStreams>
        <CheckPointRestart>Enabled</CheckPointRestart>
        <CheckPointRestartMinutes>15</CheckPointRestartMinutes>
        <CollectBMR>Disabled</CollectBMR>
        <Granular>Disabled</Granular>
        <NoClientDirect>Disabled</NoClientDirect>
        <UseAccelerator>Disabled</UseAccelerator>
        <Residence>STU_NX_TAPE_pronbu21_SL8500</Residence>
        <VolumePool>NetBackup</VolumePool>
        <DataClassification>*NULL*</DataClassification>
        <Residence>STU_PX_DD_pxddeit_files</Residence>
        <VolumePool>NetBackup</VolumePool>
        <DataClassification>*NULL*</DataClassification>
      </General>
      <Clients>
        <Client Number="1">
          <ClientHostname>10.150.131.201</ClientHostname>
          <ClientHardware>HP9000-700</ClientHardware>
          <ClientOS>HP-UX11.11</ClientOS>
          <ClientPriority>0</ClientPriority>
        </Client>
      </Clients>
      <Clients>
        <Client Number="2">
          <ClientHostname>pxhpc053</ClientHostname>
          <ClientHardware>HP9000-700</ClientHardware>
          <ClientOS>HP-UX11.11</ClientOS>
          <ClientPriority>0</ClientPriority>
        </Client>
      </Clients>
      <Clients>
        <Client Number="3">
          <ClientHostname>prdrpxx027</ClientHostname>
          <ClientHardware>HP9000-700</ClientHardware>
          <ClientOS>HP-UX11.11</ClientOS>
          <ClientPriority>0</ClientPriority>
        </Client>
      </Clients>
      <Clients>
        <Client Number="4">
          <ClientHostname>prdrpxx028</ClientHostname>
          <ClientHardware>HP9000-700</ClientHardware>
          <ClientOS>HP-UX11.11</ClientOS>
          <ClientPriority>0</ClientPriority>
        </Client>
      </Clients>
      <Clients>
        <Client Number="5">
          <ClientHostname>prdrpxx029</ClientHostname>
          <ClientHardware>HP9000-700</ClientHardware>
          <ClientOS>HP-UX11.11</ClientOS>
          <ClientPriority>0</ClientPriority>
        </Client>
      </Clients>
      <Clients>
        <Client Number="6">
          <ClientHostname>prdrpxx030</ClientHostname>
          <ClientHardware>HP9000-700</ClientHardware>
          <ClientOS>HP-UX11.11</ClientOS>
          <ClientPriority>0</ClientPriority>
        </Client>
      </Clients>
      <IncludeList>
        <Include>ALL_LOCAL_DRIVES </Include>
      </IncludeList>
    </Policy>
```

Comment: Have you considered using something like Json.NET to do this?

Comment: Hi, no. Like i said I'm new to this. I'll have look but with which area would that help me, the parsing or the generation of the xml?

Comment: Hi Riaan, I misread the question, thinking you were dealing with Json. You could use FileHelpers to convert the CSV into objects and then into XML. See details here on multiple records in a file: http://www.filehelpers.net/example/Advanced/MultiRecordEngine/

Comment: Hi, this look interesting. In the example its only distinguishing between entries based on the delimiter, do you think its possible to build a class for each of my KEYWORDS and then it will find them? Also, within each class I suppose I could add a method to perform the translation of the specific row entry I'm selecting. So that the class returns the correct string to output to XML.

Comment: And if so, am I not just going to end up using CASE again?

Comment: You would need to use a case statement in the CustomSelector based on your keywords. So you would return the class type based on the keyword in the row. The class would then output the XML as you mentioned. The main reason to use this approach is that it would be easy to update if the CSV format changes.

Comment: Can you give some examples of what you want your XML to look like for a few sample CSV lines?

Comment: Sure, I'll update the post with a sample of what I've got so far using TextFieldParser, and XDocument/XElement